# Limit the number of characters on input() function

Tags: python, python-3.x

Usually when I have to deal with multiple integers on one line I do the following:

```
line = input().split()
... work with the integers here ...
```

This never was a problem but now I have to read a line with up to 10^6 integers and which one is on range [0, 10^6].

Everytime a submit a solution to the online judge it gives me a Runtime Error and on the error log it shows:

[image: Runtime Error on the line of the input().split()]

My question is: is there a generic way of reading part of the input and leaving some of it at stdin or somehow limit my input() by spaces?

I found nothing about it on Python3 docs or searching here at StackOverflow!

PS: You can find the problem here https://www.urionlinejudge.com.br/judge/en/problems/view/1973

Comment: _How_ is it supposed to limit the input? What happens if too many characters are typed? You can trim off any excess characters after `input()` returns with a `e = e[:MAXLEN]`.

Answer (score 6):

Use `sys.stdin.read` to control how many characters you're reading at a time:

```
import sys
a = sys.stdin.read(32)
assert len(a) <= 32
```

The assertion will never fire.

Note: Be aware you may be cutting some integers off when specifying a size. For example if you do `read(4)` on input `12 3456` you may get `3` as the second number when it's actually `3456`.

Also pay attention to performance issues.

Comment: Seems nice improvement but I need some guarantees on this input. Do you know about a way of reading efficiently char by char like on C?

Comment: @weulerfilho I think in Python the only thing you can do is read a "block" and process it char-by-char.